# Scaling nodes in automata in TikZ, inside equation.

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, nodes, automata

I fail to scale the nodes (which is what I initially wanted) of the following

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\def\nd{\tikz[scale=.65, baseline=1ex,shorten >=.1pt,node distance=1.8cm,on grid,semithick,auto,
every state/.style={fill=white,draw=black,circular drop shadow,inner sep=0mm,text=black},
accepting/.style ={fill=gray,text=white}]{
\node[state] (A) {$z$};
\node[state,accepting] (B) [above right=of A] {$y$};
\node[state] (C) [below right=of B] {$x$};
\path (A) edge (B)
          edge [bend left] node {$z$} (C);}
}

\begin{document}

\[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\nd\right)\]

\end{document}
```

I used `inner sep=0mm` to reduce their size. And I tried to use `scale=.65` to make the whole smaller, because I would like to use this automata regularly as symbols in equations. What would work instead? The output is a rather huge symbol:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\def\nd{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    [font=\scriptsize,
    baseline=1ex,shorten >=.1pt,node distance=6mm,on grid,
    semithick,auto,
    every state/.style={fill=white,draw=black,circular
      drop shadow,inner sep=.3mm,text=black,minimum size=0},
    accepting/.style={fill=gray,text=white}]
    \node[state] (A) {$z$};
    \node[state,accepting] (B) [above right=of A] {$y$};
    \node[state] (C) [below right=of B] {$x$};
    \path (A) edge (B)
    edge [bend left] node[below] {$z$} (C);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\nd\right)\]

\end{document}
```

I use:

- `font=\scriptsize` to reduce the size of symbols,
- `node distance=6mm` to reduce the distance between the nodes,
- `minimum size=0` to reduce the size of the nodes,
- `inner sep=.3mm` to keep a margin between symbols and nodes.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for a way to scale not only the global coordinates but also every single node. In this case you just have to introduce `every node/.style={scale=0.65}`, like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\def\nd{\tikz[scale=.65, every node/.style={scale=0.65}, baseline=1ex,shorten >=.1pt,node distance=1.8cm,on grid,semithick,auto,
every state/.style={fill=white,draw=black,circular drop shadow,inner sep=0mm,text=black},
accepting/.style ={fill=gray,text=white}]{
\node[state] (A) {$z$};
\node[state,accepting] (B) [above right=of A] {$y$};
\node[state] (C) [below right=of B] {$x$};
\path (A) edge (B)
          edge [bend left] node {$z$} (C);}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\nd\right)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]